# Using C# library in another directory from C++ application

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I have a class, written in C#, shared between a C# and a C++ application.

To use it in the C++ app, I wrote a CLI wrapper class.

Simple diagram:

C++ App ---accesses---> CLI Library ---accesses---> C# library

Unfortunately, because of some name conflicts beyond my control, the C# and C+ applications need to be in separate directories.

What options are there for having my C++ app access these libraries in another directory?

Can I use AfxLoadLibrary in my C++ app to load the CLI library?  In that case,
would the CLI dll and the C# dll have to be in the same directory?

Can I have the managed CLI library load the C# library dynamically?

Are there any other options that I'm missing?

Comment: There are a few ways you can do this. The fastest is probably to use `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` to redirect the failed load to the other folder. The cleanest is probably a sort of proxy library that knows the interfaces, and then you can dynamically load the assembly from there.

Comment: Very unclear how the CLR even gets loaded in this scenario, it isn't automagic.  Which is probably what is missing in the first place.  Use custom CLR hosting or COM.

Comment: Currently (it's working right now with everything in the same directory), The C++ app links to the managed CLI dll which links to the C# assembly.

Comment: @Hans it is automatic. The mixed mode assembly lists mscoree.dll in its native import table causing that to be loaded by the OS loader even on old Windows versions. Since XP, the OS loader recognizes a dotnet assembly from its PE header.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Add a yourapp.exe.config file to your exe folder, listing one or more subfolders as [probing paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Put the files for each library assembly into one of the subfolders. You can put all assemblies (except the application assembly) into one folder if you want.

Comment: Are you recommending that I do that for the C++ or C# application?

Comment: @PortMan It has to be named after and alongside the exe file. It doesn't matter what kind of exe it is. I've even used a javaw.exe.config.